# Android Studio, Java and SQLite issue creating a database

Tags: java, android-studio, sqlite, android-sqlite

The issue im having is when I attempt to execute the query it doesn't have access to the execSQL part of the command, ive been stuck on this for around an hour.

```
package com.androstock.myweatherapp;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

import static android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase;

public class Database {
    SQLiteDatabase mydatabase = openOrCreateDatabase("database.db", null);

    public void onCreate() {
        mydatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TutorialsPoint(Username VARCHAR,Password VARCHAR);");
        mydatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO TutorialsPoint VALUES('admin','admin');");
    }
}
```

If somebody would be able to shed some light on where im going wrong with this that would be great thanks in advance

Comment: What is this? This is not a class method.

Comment: How should i be using this method?

Comment: There is no method.

Comment: Is the execSQL part not a method in this instance? I have never properly used Java before today what is the syntax for something like this supposed to look like?

Comment: Looks like a lack of basic understanding of java problem, not a sqlite problem. You can't have expressions like that outside of a method.

Comment: Thats exactly what it is, would you be able to show me how this should be written?

Comment: You need a basic Java tutorial, not SO.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a little mixed up with your code.

I'd suggest making the **Database** class extend (be a subclass of) the **SQLiteOpenHelper** class and overriding the **onCreate** method to create the tables in the database.

e.g.

```
public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // define constants so all names can be defined just once 
    public static final String DBNAME = "database.db"; // The database name
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1; // The version (increase it to invoke the onUpgrade method to alter the DB structure)
    public static final String TABLE_TUTORIALSPOINT = "tutorialspoint"; // The table name
    public static final String COLUMN_USERNAME = "username"; // Columns
    public static final String COLUMN_PASSWORD = "password";
    
    SQLiteDatabase mDB; //Variable to hold the SqliteDatabase

    //The Database class constructor
    public Database(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase(); //<<<<<<<<<< store the Sqlite Database opening it, (if it doesn't exist then onCreate will be called) 
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String crt_tutorialspoint_table = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_TUTORIALSPOINT + "(" +
                COLUMN_USERNAME + " VARCHAR, " +
                COLUMN_PASSWORD + " VARCHAR" +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(crt_tutorialspoint_table); // Create the table
        // Preapre to insert a row using the SQLiteDatabase convenience insert method
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COLUMN_USERNAME,"admin");
        cv.put(COLUMN_PASSWORD,"admin");
        db.insert(TABLE_TUTORIALSPOINT,null,cv);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
    }
}
```

You could then use this in an activity; something like :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    Database mMYDatabaseHelper; // Declare a Database object called mMyDatabaseHelper <<< Note will be null untill instantiated (constructed)
    SQLiteDatabase mMySQliteDatabase; // Declares an SQliteDatabase object again will be null

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
        
        mMYDatabaseHelper = new Database(this); // Construct the mMyDatabaseHelper (will create the database an insert the row)
        mMySQliteDatabase = mMYDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase(); // Set/assign sqlite database from the helper to the SqliteDatabase object
        
        // retrieve the rows in the table into a Cursor so the data can be extracted
        // Note how the names are obtained from the constants as setup in the Database class.
        Cursor mycursor = mMySQliteDatabase.query(Database.TABLE_TUTORIALSPOINT,null,null,null,null,null,null);
        // loop through all rows of the cursor
        while (mycursor.moveToNext()) {
            
            String username = mycursor.getString(mycursor.getColumnIndex(Database.COLUMN_USERNAME)); // get the username from the current row
            String password = mycursor.getString(mycursor.getColumnIndex(Database.COLUMN_PASSWORD)); // get the password from the current row
            Log.d("TABLEINFO", "Row " + String.valueOf(mycursor.getPosition() + 1) + " has a username of " + username + " and a password of " + password);
        }
        mycursor.close(); // Done with the Cursor so close it
        
        //ALL DONE if there are any rows in the table then there should be some output in the Log.
}
```

- Note typically you would have a method in the the Database class (or elsewhere depedning upon coding conventions) such that returns a Cursor rather than access the database in the activities.

### Output in the Log :-

```
D/TABLEINFO: Row 1 has a username of admin and a password of admin
```